# How to fix error: django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: URIs not supported

Tags: python, django, linux, amazon-web-services, sqlite

in my Django project in Linux machine (in AWS) I'm using:

- Python 3.5.1
- Django 1.11.7

I've created virtual environment for my project and all dependencies are installed perfectly there. For the database I'm using **sqlite3**. See below for the version details.

```
>>>import sqlite3
>>>sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
>>>sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
(3, 7, 17)
```

In **settings.py** the *DATABASES* section is as below:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
      'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
   }
}
```

While running runserver I am getting one exception as **sqlite3.NotSupportedError: URIs not supported** which is generating an error **django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: URIs not supported**, that I am not able to fix.

I have gone through the posts like [djangoproject.com](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28376) and [google.forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/toPdwWpudbg), but still not able to understand the reason for this error. I also tried to do *python manage.py makemigrations* but same error coming for that also.

Note: In windows machine this my project is running fine.

Please see the traceback below:

```
# python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors. 
<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f07ff09c2f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site- packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 198, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  sqlite3.NotSupportedError: URIs not supported

  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 128, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 422, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/tech/poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 198, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: URIs not supported
```

Please help to understand and fix this error. There is no related posts in stack for this issue nor I have found anything relevant in google.

Comment: check the path specified in the BASE_DIR setting.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas regarding this issue? Whats the reason and how to fix this? Please let me know.

Comment: I have the same problem, it's broke on my machine, but all my co-workers don't get the bug.

I debugged in django's code, and found that in `django.db.backends.sqlite3.base` on about line 194 it sets `uri` `True`. If i comment that out, it works.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar problem. Turns out Django 2.1 is incompatible with sqlite 3.6.20. Downgrade to version 2.0.x and you should be good. The issue has been raised and is labelled "Closed bug- wontfix" [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29624)

Answer (score 1):

1.You have to check sqlite3 version first. It should be `3.X`
My configuration is `Python 3.7`, `django 2.1.7` and `sqlite3`. 
You can check sqlite3 version as below:
`>>import sqlite3`

`>>sqlite3.version`
'2.6.0'
`>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version_info`
(3, 6, 20)`

2. Check in `"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py"`
   Look for line" `kwargs.update({'check_same_thread': False, 'uri': False})`
   If 'uri' is True, then change it to False as root.
   After code change, reboot your machine and run `python runserver migrate`
   This should resolve your issue.

Also, you can try changing the DATABASE['NAME'] with hardcoded db.sqli3 file name in the `SETTINGS.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while connecting to Postgresql on Ubuntu. I downgraded the Django version from the latest to 3.2.15. This resolved the problem for me. I hope this helps.